# Using culture propertie

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following problem, I use on my pages, on my pc development, culture = "es-cu" when I upload to the production server they reported the following error:
'es-cu' is not a valid value for the 'culture' attribute.
On both computers I have installed until FrameWork 4.5.2. What should I have to change or reconfigure on the server to it's work function properly.

Salu2
Otto

Comment: I don't see that abbreviation here, what culture is the target?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Comment: when I use this code: CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
        Response.Write("<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Country Name</th><th>Language-Country code</th></tr>");
        foreach (CultureInfo cul in cinfo)
        {
            Response.Write("<tr>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + cul.DisplayName + " </td><td> " + cul.Name + "</td>");
            Response.Write("</tr>");
        }
        Response.Write("</table>");